# Block editor: content resets to the previous state in "Edit as HTML" by clicking somewhere outside of the editing window

Tags: block-editor, visual-editor, post-editor, html-editor

When I'm adding my custom block and then trying to edit it in "Edit as HTML" mode, any changes reset to the previous state every time when I click outside the editing window. Let say default HTML in my block is `<div class="wp-block-my-custom-video-box"></div>`, if I make some changes, let say `<div class="wp-block-my-custom-video-box">some text</div>` `some text` will disappear. This issue related to WordPress ver. 5.3.2, with ver. 5.2.5 everything works fine.
Help me figure out, please, what can cause such strange behavior?
[image]

this is a simplified example of the component: https://pastebin.com/RqQP0LCM

Comment: Does this only affect your block, or all blocks?

Comment: Are there any JS errors in the console?

Comment: Yes, it affects only my block, but I can't find what part may do it.

Comment: No, there are no JS errors in the console.

Comment: I added an example of the code